# Flatten and sort nested array of object by its array value

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, performance

```
// My data is like this
const data = [
  { 
    id: 1,
    color: "red",
    time: [ 
     { start: new Date("2021-4-3"), end: new Date("2021-4-4") }, 
     { start: new Date("2021-4-2"), end: new Date("2021-4-3") }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    color: "blue",
    time: [ 
     { start: new Date("2021-4-2"), end: new Date("2021-4-3") }
    ]
  }
]
```

And I want to sort time then adjust the data like below.

```
[
  { id: "1-0", start: new Date("2021-4-2"), end: new Date("2021-4-3"), color: "red" },
  { id: "1-1", start: new Date("2021-4-3"), end: new Date("2021-4-4"), color: "red" },
  { id: "2-0", start: new Date("2021-4-2"), end: new Date("2021-4-3"), color: "blue" },
]
```

I want to know is there have **better algorithm** to handle this situation? Below is my attempt.
(I also attempted ES6 syntax `reduce`, `flatMap` and `flat`, but I can't find the better way to handle this situation.)

```
let arr = [];
let timeLength = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  timeLength = data[i].time.length;
  if (timeLength !== 1) {
    data[i].time.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.start) - new Date(b.start)); // sort time
  }
  for (let j = 0; j < timeLength; j++) {
    arr.push({
      id: data[i].id + "-" + i,
      color: data[i].color,
      start: data[i].time[j].start,
      end: data[i].time[j].end,
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I answered but now I'm realizing you're looking for a _better_ solution... does yours not work?

Comment: This code is work, but I just want to figure it out how to enhance this code's performance. BTW,  I also run your code @Nick, it will dropdown like 25% performance in js bench, but your code is very neat and thanks for your sharing. ;)

Comment: The step with the highest complexity is sorting the list of times. Unless you can find a way to do this without sorting, I think the performance can't be greatly improved.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur, can you explain, if I can ignore sorting time by using db or sql, what is the best answer in your opinion? By using recursive algorithm or something?

Comment: @PoWenChen your iterative approach is better, because recursion is just going to add a recursive overhead to it

Comment: @PoWenChen what is the average length of ```id.time``` in your case?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur it depend on the user input, so I can't give you a specific answer, maybe 15-20.

Comment: As your code works, this question is better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one substantial slow-down in your code that I see: in the `sort` call, you are calling `new Date(...)` repeatedly.  There is no reason for this.  Your fields are already dates so you can just use them as is.  I would prefer to use `flatMap` and `map`, so my version would look like this:

```js
const convert = (data) =>
  data .flatMap (
    ({time, ...rest}) => [...time] .sort ((a, b) => a .start - b .start) 
                                   .map (t => ({...rest, ...t}))
  )

const data = [{id: 1, color: "red", time: [{start: new Date("2021-4-3"), end: new Date("2021-4-4")}, {start: new Date("2021-4-2"), end: new Date("2021-4-3")}]}, {id: 2, color: "blue", time: [{start: new Date("2021-4-2"), end: new Date("2021-4-3")}]}]

console .log (convert (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

If instead of `Date` objects, you had ISO formatted strings, such as `2021-04-03` you could also sort directly without any `Date` instantiation:

```js
   [...time] .sort (({start: s1}, {start: s2}) => s1 < s2 ? -1 : s1 > s2 ? 1 : 0)
```

And if you had absolutely no use remaining for your input object, you could skip the shallow clone of `time`, replacing `[...time] .sort (...)` with `time .sort (...)`.  But that wouldn't gain much and the mutation of your original data might be problematic.

Comment: Wow, you actually nail it. Your answer in the js benchmark are faster 50% then my solution.